# VBA code calling a VB6 dll method under regular account gets ODBC Driver error but works when run as Administrator

Tags: registry, dll, odbc, vb6

I have a Word template (.dot) open in Word 2016 that references a VB6 dll. When I run the VBA code with my regular user account I receive an error message. When I run it under my Admin account, I do not get the error. The error occurs on the referenced objects "Load()" method call:

```
Dim m_Manager As New PrefixService.Manager
Call m_Manager.Load(subjectID, ClientID)
```

The exact error is:

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I have done some research but am in unfamiliar territory. I keep reading things about the registry and ODBC. There is an entry in the registry for PrefixService.Manager and users have read access to it. As for the ODBC Data Source Administrator, I am not sure what to look for but search results mention connection strings and Microsoft Access a lot even though I am not sure what they have to do with me referencing a dll and executing code from it. Microsoft Access 2016 is installed. I have run the Windows Sysinternals ListDlls command on the WINWORD process and saw that the dll was never loaded, however, under my Admin account, I can see the dll gets loaded. While in ODBC Data Source Administrator, I ran a trace, but unfortunately I do not speak ODBC and find it difficult to understand.I believe the following section contains the information about the issue:

```
o "u"           1260-ca4    ENTER SQLDriverConnectW 
    HDBC                0x0BA01850
    HWND                0x00000000
    WCHAR *             0x5A768B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 
    WCHAR *             0x5A768B34 
    SWORD                       -3 
    SWORD *             0x00000000
    UWORD                        0 <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

o "u"           1260-ca4    EXIT  SQLDriverConnectW  with return code -1 (SQL_ERROR)
    HDBC                0x0BA01850
    HWND                0x00000000
    WCHAR *             0x5A768B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"
    SWORD                       -3 
    WCHAR *             0x5A768B34 
    SWORD                       -3 
    SWORD *             0x00000000
    UWORD                        0     <SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT>

    DIAG [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) 

o "u"           1260-ca4    ENTER SQLGetDiagRecW 
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
    SQLHANDLE           0x0BA01850
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 
    SQLWCHAR *          0x0036E93C
    SQLINTEGER *        0x0036E514
    SQLWCHAR *          0x0036E53C 
    SQLSMALLINT                512 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x0036E524



o "u"           1260-ca4    EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
    SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
    SQLHANDLE           0x0BA01850
    SQLSMALLINT                  1 
    SQLWCHAR *          0x0036E93C [       5] "IM002"
    SQLINTEGER *        0x0036E514 (0)
    SQLWCHAR *          0x0036E53C [      91] "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
    SQLSMALLINT                512 
    SQLSMALLINT *       0x0036E524 (91)
```

I am now at a loss other than it appears to be permissions based. Oh and the OS is Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: As admin try right clicking on DLL and checking the permissions on the security tab.

Comment: "Users" had "Read & Execute" and "Read" permissions on the dll. Just for testing purposes, I changed permissions on it to "Full Control" and ran it and received the same error. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: It might be that the ODBC DSN has been set up as a user DSN under your administrator account.  Try running odbcad32 as both your normal user account and your admin account and see what is listed under the User DSN and System DSN.  If you have something under the admin one that isn't under the normal user one then you could try copying the settings across.

Comment: I appreciate the help. The entries on both the User DSN and and System DSN tabs have the exact same entries and the same settings within the Configure window

Comment: This is going to be tricky to help remotely but you've done well so far what what you've found.To answer one of your questions, I suspect the Load method in the VB6 DLL is accessing a database to retrieve the values it is loading.  It is using ODBC to access the database.  The ODBC function SQLDriverConnect is used to connect to a database.  One of the parameters to that is shown as 'WCHAR *             0x5A768B34 [      -3] "******\ 0"' in your trace.  This parameter contains the details of how to connect to the database. (cont...)

Comment: What might be useful is to capture the trace again but this time running as admin.  You'll see a lot more calls in there but you should be able to find the call to SQLDriverConnect and, maybe, see what it is using to connect.  It may well be that the VB6 DLL is retrieving this connection information from the current user part of the registry and there is only an entry under the admin user.  See what you can find in the log when running as admin and post that here

Comment: I don't know why, but when I run the trace, it is empty... for safe measure I tried both the SysWOW64 and System32 odbcad.exe. As a side note, this is a newly spun up vm for testing the upgrade to Word 2016 and I believe there is a problem with the Image. I decided to just try and install Word 2016 on my own machine and everything runs fine. I will keep trying to get the trace.

Answer (score 0):

came here to say I have same error code -2147467259 (80004005)
it turned out that the old Excel sheet my users were running is only compatible with Office x86

I had made a new server with Office 2019 x64 - as soon as I reinstalled office to x86, the macros worked fine

the ODBC instances was represented both in x32 and x64.

So check if you have x64 versus x86 issues :)